# Getting TSV file output excluding 2 resource types from the az resource list in Azure CLI

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-cli

Kindly concern that I need to get the azure resource list from the azure CLI excluding 2 kinds of resource types and output the file to a TSV file. I was able do this particular operation via PowerShell from the following command.

PowerShell Command - get-azresource | where ResourceType -notmatch microsoft.network/privatednszones/virtualnetworklinks | where ResourceType -notmatch microsoft.insights/actiongroups | export-csv C:\Users\7.csv

I need to get this result from Azure CLI excluding the mentioned resource types to TSV file (Since we cannot get the Azure CLI output in CSV)

PLEASE HELP AT YOUR EARLIEST CONVENIANCE, I WILL HIGHLY APPRECIATE IF YOU CAN.

Thanks & Regards,
Anon.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify tab as the delimiter in your export-csv, as follows  (note the use of backtick t to indicate tab) This may end up putting quotes around some of your values.:

```
PowerShell Command - get-azresource | 
where ResourceType -notmatch 
 microsoft.network/privatednszones/virtualnetworklinks | 
where ResourceType -notmatch microsoft.insights/actiongroups | 
export-csv C:\Users\7.csv -delimiter `t
```